# Equal likelihoods for any two samples with equal standard deviations (normal distribution)

Tags: st.statistics

I have a conjecture that for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, each with non-zero but finite sample standard deviations,
$$\sum_{i = 1}^n{\log{\varphi(\frac{x_i-\overline{x}}{s_x})}} =
 \sum_{i = 1}^n{\log{\varphi(\frac{y_i - \overline{y}}{s_y})}},$$
where $\varphi$ is the p.d.f. of the standard normal distribution and $\overline{x}$ and $s_x$ are the sample mean and Bessel-corrected sample standard deviation of $x$, respectively (similarly for $y$).

I have not proven this result, but have evidence from numerical simulations that it is correct, both for large (~500) and small (1+) $n$. My question is simply: does this result have a name?

Note: if the conjecture is in fact false, it is nevertheless empirically the case that numerical simulations reveal any error is within numerical tolerances, and so any answer that can reflect on why the error is so suggestively small would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This conjecture is of course false.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Perfectly possible, although I've tested with numerical simulations and didn't find occasions where it failed. Care to share a counter example?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Is it? It seems to me that the $\log \varphi$ of a number is just the square of that number divided by $2$, plus a constant, so this is saying that the average square of the difference of one set of data points from their mean, divided by the variance, is the average square of the difference of another set of data points from their mean, divided by the variance. In other words it follows from the definition of variance.

Comment: @WillSawin : Usually, $\sigma$ denotes the true, "population" standard deviation (s.d.), whereas the sample s.d. is usually denoted by $s$. Similarly, usually $\bar x$ and $\mu_x$ denote the sample and population means, respectively. Therefore **and because** the title is about equal likelihoods, I had to assume that $\mu_x,\mu_y,\sigma_x,\sigma_y$ pertain to the populations, and then the identity is clearly false. Otherwise -- that is, if these symbols pertain to the samples -- the identity is true and trivial, as you noted.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Sure, fair point. I was guessing in part based on the fact that sircolinton mentioned numerical evidence (which wouldn't exist in the population interpretation unless the precision of the calculation was very low compared to the sample size for some reason) and the fact that populations and their distributions are not specified.

Comment: @WillSawin : I thought the numerics somehow concerned simulated random samples. But because of the likelihoods in the title, it did not even occur to me that $\mu_x$ and $\sigma_x$ might denote the sample mean and the sample standard deviation -- then there would be no likelihood anywhere in the post except for its title.

Comment: I didn't mean to trigger confusion w.r.t. whether $\mu_x$ and $\sigma_x$ are population vs sample. I will edit to clarify. My numerical simulations used the sample mean and sample standard deviation. The mention of likelihood in the title is due to that being related to the application I was exploring, but it doesn't carry greater significance than that. Happy to change the title if there's a better suggestion.

Comment: @sircolinton : As Will Sawin noted, the identity in question follows immediately from the definition of $\phi$ and the definitions of the sample mean and of the sample standard deviation. This completely answers your question.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Fair enough, although my question is whether this result has a name. This result has been particularly useful for me in a particular application, and so I'd like to do some further reading to see whether it's been applied in other applications.